# mongodb compound or individual indexes

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, database

I need some advice on how to properly set up indexes w/mongodb.

Let say my data collection is something like this:

Players

```
 - age
 - scores
 - fouls
 - yellow cards
 - red cards
 - offsides
```

My problem with that is that my potential queries can cover all the combination of indexes, for example:

```
Get players that age < 30 and yellow card > 3
Get players that age < 30 and yellow card > 3 and red_cards >6
Get players that age < 30 and red_cards card > 3 and scores > 2
Get players that scores < 30 and yellow card > 3 and fouls < 6 and red_cards >2
Get players that scores < 30 and yellow card > 3 and fouls < 6 and red_cards >2 and age > 25
```

What's the best way to assign my indexes in this case? If my collection has 6 fields like in my examples, will I need 36 indexes?
Or would it be a better alternative to have one field per index?

Comment: You can't have more than 64 indexes per collection. But, the recommendation is stay **far** below that number. If your data insert rate is high it's even more important to keep the number small. Read this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question depends on you collection size, query rate, distribution of different types of queries(queries with some set of parameters have higher rate then others), etc.

If size of you collection less then 100k(*for example*) documents, you can be convinced that all your queries will be *fast*, even they don't use indexes and do sequential scans all the time.

To the the other hand, if you have 1000 such queries per second, it will not work as expected, and in this case you have to use profiler(**system.profile**) to determine distribution of different types of queries. When you get this distribution, it will be pretty obvious, which indexes you should create.

Your main goal should be, to reduce amount of data(index+documents) you read to satisfy query.

Finally, you can increase read throughput by creating [MongoDB ReplicaSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the document size will not be bigger then 10k at avarage, but i am going to have alot of documents like that ( around 800 Milion ) , we designing a system for high query rate and high throughput . what would you recommend to do in this case ?

Comment: @BmaorLO, if 10К is the size of single document, then you should mention this in question, because this is important. Your original description was about 6 fields, and such document will be ~0.1K(not 10K) in size. Can you write more clearly what is average document size, total document count, query rate, structure of your documents and typical queries.

Comment: You are right , i am sorry for not being clear from the beginning.
after i did more research during this weekend , the numbers will be like the following.
The document will look like in the original question posted here.
i will have 1 Bilion records like this 
each document will be 0.1K ( and not 10k sorry about this ) .
I need to support as much fast reads as possible .

What would you recommend to do in this case ?

Comment: @BmaorLO, it very hard to query 100Gb(0.1K*10^9) of data. In this case you mast have index for any query. Use profiler to determine which indexes you need the most. Sorry, no concrete advices for you. You also should try relational databases, you may benefit from partial indexes.

Comment: Thanks @amezhenin i appreciate your time and effort to help me. it's play time :)